# Proving that $\exp\left(-\frac{a + b}{2 x}\right)\left[ b + (a - x)\exp\left(\frac{a + b}{x}\right) + x\right]$ changes signs?

Tags: calculus

Is there any way to prove that $$\exp\left(-\frac{a + b}{2 x}\right)\left[ b + (a - x)\exp\left(\frac{a + b}{x}\right) + x\right]$$ is positive for small values of x, and negative for large values of x? If so, is there any way to find at which point does the function change sign, or in other words, for what x does $f(a,b,x)=0$?

Constraints: $a>0$ ; $b>0$ ; $x>0$ ; $b>a$

Comment: The term $\exp(-\frac{a+b}{2x})$ is always positive, so it does not affect the sign whatsoever.

Comment: You are right, but what about the remaining part of the function? Is there a concrete way I can deal with it?

Comment: I've managed to show that the expression is positive for $x<a$, and I'm having a bit more trouble with the second part. I haven't yet used the fact that $a<b$, so that must play a role in the second part.

Comment: Yes it does play a role, if a>b, then the function is always positive for any positive value of the variables. I thank you for your help in advance :).

Answer (score 0):

The first exponential term doesn't affect the sign, because it's always positive, so we can ignore it, and focus on:

$g(x) = b + (a-x)e^{(a+b)/x} + x$

When $x<a$, the factor $(a-x)$ is positive, so all terms are positive, and we have $g(x)>0$

That shows that your function is positive for small values of $x$, which is one third of your question.

---

For the second part, we need to do more work. One thing we'll need is the inequality: For $x>0$, we have $e^x>1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2}$.

We need to show that, for large $x$,

$g(x) = b + (a-x)e^{(a+b)/x} + x < 0$

Since we can assume $a-x<0$, this is equivalent to:

$\begin{align}
e^{(a+b)/x} > \frac{x+b}{x-a} &= 1+\frac{a+b}{x-a} \\
&= 1 + \frac{a+b}{x}\frac{x}{x-a} \\
&= 1 + \frac{a+b}{x}\left(1+\frac{a}{x-a}\right) \\
&= 1 +  \frac{a+b}{x} + \frac{a+b}{x}\frac{a}{x-a} \\
&= 1 +  \frac{a+b}{x} + \frac12\left(\frac{a+b}{x}\right)^2\frac{2ax}{(a+b)(x-a)} \\
&= 1 +  \frac{a+b}{x} + \frac12\left(\frac{a+b}{x}\right)^2\frac{2a}{(a+b)}\frac{x}{x-a}
\end{align}$

It now suffices to show that $\frac{2a}{(a+b)}\frac{x}{x-a}<1$ for sufficiently large $x$. As $x$ grows, the fraction $\frac{x}{x-a}$ gets arbitrarily close to $1$, so eventually it is smaller than $\frac{a+b}{2a}$, which is greater than $1$ because $a<b$.

When that happens, we can use our quadratic inequality above to provide the second result you needed.

---

Solving for $x$ where $g(x)=0$ seems hard. I'm not sure I know of an analytic way to do that, but for specific values of $a$ and $b$, it could always be solved numerically.

Comment: My gratitude dear Tony :).